# Oracle vb.net select parameter dbnull.value

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle

This works:

```
 Dim stSQL as String = "Select ID From Table Where COL Is Null"
 Dim cmd As New OracleCommand
 cmd.Connection = ...
 cmd.CommandText = stSQL
 cmd.BindByName = True

    Try
        Dim oRet As Object = cmd.ExecuteScalar

        If oRet IsNot Nothing Then
            If oRet > 0 Then
                ...
           End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
```

If I change the sql string to use a parameter:

```
Dim stSQL as String = "Select ID From Table Where COL = :COL"

and add:

cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("COL", DBNull.Value))
```

It doesn't work... (oRet = Nothing)  Any ideas? -Thanks.

Oracle 12c, VS2017, Oracle.DataAccess v4.112.3.0

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` means "not defined", you cannot make comparison on equal. Anything compared by `= NULL` returns false.

You must use `WHERE COL IS NULL`.